# MTLTextureDescriptor width/height greater than the maximum allowed size, but working in another project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, metal

In [this sample project](https://github.com/hydrixos/scenekit-marble-demo) I'm running a texture that's 13200x10200 and it's working fine. When I run the code to my own project it errors out saying the max width/height is 8192. I use the same simulator and can't find any difference in my schema or project settings. What am I overlooking? I am able to build to my iPad mini 5.

Comment: Are both projects running with validation enabled? As far as I know, simulators run with a very restricted feature set, basically `.apple2` feature set, which means that texture dimensions are going to be limited to 8192px as per https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf

Comment: @JustSomeGuy both projects have API Validation checked in the Scheme->Run->Diagnostics tab. I did find references to this table elsewhere, but I could not find info on why it was limiting even new devices, such as iPhone 13's. Not to mention it's only doing it in one project.

Comment: I mean, it's a simulator. You probably have different versions of simulator somehow and they behave differently. But still, simulator only supports the lowest feature level.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy using the exact same simulator as a build target. I can open both apps at the same time.